# how to bring vertical line in table

Tags: tables, tabularx

Here is a table I wrote

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{15pt}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h]
        \begin{tabular}{| l | l | c | c |}
            \hline
        1 & 2 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Content 3 and 4}  \\[20pt] \hline 
        5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ \cline{2-4}
        9 & 10 & 11 &  \multirow{2}{*}{Rows 3 and 4} \\
        \cline{1-3}
        13 & 14 & 15  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

this table appears as follows on my laptop.
[image: table without vertical line]
I have encircled the bottorm right hand corner where the vertical line I expect is missing.
What should I do in this case.

Comment: Add an ampersand in the last row.

Comment: thanks this worked.

Comment: I changed the code a little bit `  9 & 10 & \multirow{2}{*}{Rows 3 and 4} & 12  \\
  \cline{1-2}
  13 & 14 &  & 16 \\ \hline
` so below 12 I want to bring a horizontal line.

Comment: Add `\cline{4-4}` just after `\cline{1-2}`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the last row of your tabular from

```
    13 & 14 & 15 \\ \hline
```

to

```
    % not the "&" added after "15"
    13 & 14 & 15 & \\ \hline
```

Comment: the comment & added after 15 looks confusing it looks it is just opposite of what you wanted to type

Comment: @koeradoera `&` is used to specify how many columns a row of tabular contains. Each row of a 4-column tabular may spread 4 or less columns. Since the trailing vertical line is part of the last cell in a row, that `&` after "15" is required, otherwise the last row spreads only 3 columns hence the last vertical line is not drawn.