# spanning in both the directions example from wikibooks table tutorial and getting a full vertical line

Tags: tables

I am reading a solved example given on [wikibooks tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) page in the section ***spanning in both directions simultaneously***
they gave following example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|c|c|l}
    \cline{3-6}
    & & \multicolumn{4}{ c| }{Primes} \\ \cline{3-6}
    & & 2 & 3 & 5 & 7 \\ \cline{1-6}
    \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{\multirow{2}{*}{Powers} } &
    \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{504} & 3 & 2 & 0 & 1 &     \\ \cline{2-6}
    \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{}                        &
    \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{540} & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 &     \\ \cline{1-6}
    \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{\multirow{2}{*}{Powers} } &
    \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{gcd} & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & min \\ \cline{2-6}
    \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{}                        &
    \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{lcm} & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 & max \\ \cline{1-6}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

its output is as below
[image: wiki books spanning in both directions]
however I added a simple | in line `\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|c|c|l |}`
to get a vertical line for the last column 
so it becomes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{makecell}
%\sisetup{
%round-mode = places,
%round-precision = 2, 
%}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}



\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|c|c|l |}
    \cline{3-6}
    & & \multicolumn{4}{ c| }{Primes} \\ \cline{3-6}
    & & 2 & 3 & 5 & 7 \\ \cline{1-6}
    \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{\multirow{2}{*}{Powers} } &
    \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{504} & 3 & 2 & 0 & 1 &     \\ \cline{2-6}
    \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{}                        &
    \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{540} & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 &     \\ \cline{1-6}
    \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{\multirow{2}{*}{Powers} } &
    \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{gcd} & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & min \\ \cline{2-6}
    \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{}                        &
    \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{lcm} & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 & max \\ \cline{1-6}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

but I did not get a full vertical line at the last column  instead what I get is
[image: half vertical line]
so I want to know where is my understanding wrong. Why I did not get a full vertical line as I expected.

Comment: You are missing two `&` , one in the first, another in the second row.

Comment: `\cline{3-6}
    & & \multicolumn{4}{ c| }{Primes} & \\ \cline{3-6}
    & & 2 & 3 & 5 & 7 &  \\ \cline{1-6}` should give you the sedired result.

Comment: I have added the mising `&` right before the `\\ ` in the two lines.

Comment: By the way: This is the same problem and the same solution as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542975/134144

Comment: yes I get you I still was not able to think that missing & could be a problem here. The usage of & in this way is some thing I am not able to think.

Comment: By omitting the `&`you basically end the row after columm number 6. So the vertical line after column number 7 is not drawn.

Comment: I tried one more simple table 
`\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill} } | c | c | c | r | }
 \hline
 label 1 & label 2 & label 3 & label 4 \\
 \hline 
 item 1  & item 2  & item 3  & item 4  \\
 \hline
\end{tabular*}`
this table has small small horizontal line coming at each row in left most can you tell how is this happening I have a screenshot here you can see https://i.imgur.com/KsPPSX6.jpg

Comment: `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ | @{\extracolsep{\fill} }c | c | c | r | }` should correct that. But honestly: I would avoid vertical lines in tables, especially in `tabular*`.

Comment: I tried the code you mention but this appears like this https://imgur.com/iFUrfbz two vertical lines parallel vertical lines at left most, I am just practicing tables for my own so I am trying how lines and vertical lines come in it.

Comment: The image you posted in your last comment is produced when using `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ | @{\extracolsep{\fill} }|c | c | c | r | } ` which is different from my previous comment.

Comment: oh ok now I could correct it.

Comment: I want to know this `@{\extracolsep{\fill} }`  will this apply to each column in or only on the first column, the way you mentioned in `|@{\extracolsep{\fill} }c|` to me it seems it applies only to 1 column.

Comment: also don't load so many packages, just load ones you need. don't load tabu for example and in examples you post here don't load any packages not used in the example, it just makes it harder for people to help you

Comment: Most style guides recommend not using vertical rules. You are loading the `booktabs` package, If using booktabs then definitely never use vertical rules.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle how does one knows which package should not be used with another one is this documented some where.

Comment: The space in your image is due to the space you are adding here `@{\extracolsep{\fill} }` use `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` but most tables are better without using this and without having vertical rules.

Comment: @koeradoera always start with _no_ packages and just add a package if you need it.

Comment: but tabu is completely broken and should not be used at all.